# OneNote API - Cannot get Pages

Tags: c#, onenote

I have been playing around with the OneNote API, and have been successful at getting Notebooks,Sections,Pages.

Today however I have been unsuccessful getting the pages using the `Section.pagesUrl`.

My Request: `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19161/pages`

Where `0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19161` is the ID of the section.

This has worked before, but has somehow stopped working.

Right before this request I successfully get the Notebooks, then once finding correct notebook from the returned list, get the sections and again find the correct section.

The response I am getting is 200(OK) but an empty array:

```
{

  "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/sections('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119161')/pages",
  "value":[



  ]

}
```

Although I can see the same Notbooks and Sections in my OneNote client. And sections do have pages. But I am not getting them any more.

Any reason why this could be happening?

Could it be a bug on your side or is there something I'm missing?

I add the `Bearer` token to the `HttpClient` like so:

```
_client = new HttpClient();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _tokenService.AccessToken);
```

Which seemed to work last week, and it is still working for getting Notebooks/Sections

---

**EDIT: Requests + Responses**

Request that works (getting sections):

```
GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19159/sections HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 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
Accept: application/json
Host: www.onenote.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-CorrelationId: d3c85fde-c8e0-4e4e-a4df-87a3f57f146e
X-UserSessionId: d3c85fde-c8e0-4e4e-a4df-87a3f57f146e
X-OfficeFE: OneNoteServiceFrontEnd_IN_0
X-OfficeVersion: 16.0.6023.1561
X-OfficeCluster: neu-www.onenote.com
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Request-Processing-Time: 828.1859 ms
OData-Version: 4.0
Preference-Applied: odata.include-annotations=*
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 12:10:58 GMT
Content-Length: 3135

{
  "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119159')/sections(parentNotebook(id,name,self),parentSectionGroup(id,name,self))","value":[
    {
      "isDefault":false,"pagesUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!41276/pages","name":"Agily","createdBy":"LnDSoft Test","lastModifiedBy":"LnDSoft Test","lastModifiedTime":"2015-07-23T11:39:46.9Z","id":"0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!41276","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!41276","createdTime":"2015-07-15T23:39:22.44Z","parentNotebook@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119159')/sections('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2141276')/parentNotebook(id,name,self)/$entity","parentNotebook":{
        "id":"0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19159","name":"Agily","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19159"
      },"parentSectionGroup@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119159')/sections('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2141276')/parentSectionGroup(id,name,self)/$entity","parentSectionGroup":null
    },{
      "isDefault":false,"pagesUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19161/pages","name":"AgilyTest","createdBy":"LnDSoft Test","lastModifiedBy":"M C","lastModifiedTime":"2015-07-21T23:16:18.85Z","id":"0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19161","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19161","createdTime":"2015-01-04T23:50:32.41Z","parentNotebook@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119159')/sections('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119161')/parentNotebook(id,name,self)/$entity","parentNotebook":{
        "id":"0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19159","name":"Agily","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19159"
      },"parentSectionGroup@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119159')/sections('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119161')/parentSectionGroup(id,name,self)/$entity","parentSectionGroup":null
    },{
      "isDefault":false,"pagesUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!41275/pages","name":"OtherSection","createdBy":"LnDSoft Test","lastModifiedBy":"LnDSoft Test","lastModifiedTime":"2015-07-15T23:36:15.037Z","id":"0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!41275","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!41275","createdTime":"2015-07-15T23:35:13.9Z","parentNotebook@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119159')/sections('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2141275')/parentNotebook(id,name,self)/$entity","parentNotebook":{
        "id":"0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19159","name":"Agily","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19159"
      },"parentSectionGroup@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119159')/sections('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2141275')/parentSectionGroup(id,name,self)/$entity","parentSectionGroup":null
    }
  ]
}
```

Request that does not work (getting pages, using the URL from above):

Request:

```
GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19161/pages HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 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
Accept: application/json
Host: www.onenote.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-CorrelationId: fe872c95-f8af-41e3-b019-4e6504a5e8df
X-UserSessionId: fe872c95-f8af-41e3-b019-4e6504a5e8df
X-OfficeFE: OneNoteServiceFrontEnd_IN_0
X-OfficeVersion: 16.0.6023.1561
X-OfficeCluster: neu-www.onenote.com
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Request-Processing-Time: 703.1688 ms
OData-Version: 4.0
Preference-Applied: odata.include-annotations=*
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 12:10:58 GMT
Content-Length: 143

{
  "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/sections('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119161')/pages","value":[

  ]
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:** Still not working

Request:

```
GET https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/sections/0-2B36C9469D6FE2E!19161/pages HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 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
Accept: application/json
Host: www.onenote.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-CorrelationId: 7cb781ec-36d4-4485-b6c1-a48f7e536298
X-UserSessionId: 7cb781ec-36d4-4485-b6c1-a48f7e536298
X-OfficeFE: OneNoteServiceFrontEnd_IN_5
X-OfficeVersion: 16.0.6023.1561
X-OfficeCluster: neu-www.onenote.com
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONi TELi CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDi OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Request-Processing-Time: 671.9287 ms
OData-Version: 4.0
Preference-Applied: odata.include-annotations=*
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 28 Jul 2015 02:21:40 GMT
Content-Length: 143

{
  "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/sections('0-2B36C9469D6FE2E%2119161')/pages","value":[

  ]
}
```

You can see in the below screenshot that pages exist

for Agily (Notebook) -> Agily (Section)

[image: OneNote - Pages Exist]

Comment: Could you post the response HTTP headers of a failing request please so we can investigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been investigating this issue for you today. I was wondering if you could try this request again?

Our storage layer experienced some failures over the weekend that could possibly explain the issue so I wanted to verify with you that you are seeing the issue still.

As far as I can tell from the request that you posted and the logs on our end, there is nothing wrong syntactically with the request and no obvious logic errors on our end, so the investigation is currently pointing at the storage layer as possibly being the culprit.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: It's still not working. See edit 2. Thanks for looking into it though. :-(

Comment: Bummer. Okay, investigating. Thanks for your patience with us.

NickM - sorry :(. Doing my best to help without reputation (yet).

Comment: 2 questions for you:
(1) is your section password-protected?
(2) can you please touch a page (add some text, delete some text) and record the approximate time (UTC) that you did so?

(If your section is password-protected, we unfortunately do not support that at this time, in which case there is no need to do #2.)

Comment: Cancel that. We were able to confirm #1 is not true and we were able to find instances of edits you've made in the past which satisfies #2. It sounds like this is due to the content being shared with the calling user rather than being owned by the calling user. I will get back to you with more after we discuss this fully.

Comment: SO, what is the solution? It doesn't work as expected. But on test site it works (dev.onenote.com). But on my site same request doesn't have correct response. Just count 0 and empty value